# Is it possible to pass a lambda expression as an argument of a print function in a f-String?

Tags: python, lambda

Wanted to know why I it shows an error when I try this:

```
print(f"equal to: {lambda h, c : sqrt(h**2 + c**2)}")  # error
```

and it worked when I tried this:

```
print("equal to", lambda h, c : sqrt(h**2 + c**2))  # doesn't show error
```

Why is there an error on the first one? Is it a bug or not? Is it not possible to use lambda expressions within a f-string?

extra details: I was using Visual Studio Code and it showed: Expected ":" Pylance

Comment: I'm not sure why that's a syntax error, but the first way works if you just wrap the `lambda` in `()`s (although, you never call the function, so it just print's the `lambda`'s identity). It may be that the open body of the `lambda` leads to parsing ambiguities without `()` wrapping.

Comment: As noted above, it requires parentheses to avoid the syntax error... but more importantly, *what are you trying to achieve here*? What is your **expected output**??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals):

> Expressions in formatted string literals are treated like regular Python expressions surrounded by parentheses, with a few exceptions. An empty expression is not allowed, and **both lambda and assignment expressions := must be surrounded by explicit parentheses**. [...]

```
>>> print(f"equal to: {(lambda h, c : sqrt(h**2 + c**2))}")
equal to: <function <lambda> at 0x10228af70>
```

As to *why*, I suspect the amount of proper parsing that can be done during lexical analysis is limited, and so the parentheses are needed to help the parser.

(The above link includes a snippet of the grammar used to define f-strings, which hints at the differences between replacement fields and arbitrary Python expressions, but I will beg off trying to provide an explanation for them.)